# highlight row when rowdetails is expanded

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Is there any way to get it highlight the row when rowdetails is expanded in ngx-datatable ?

we can get highlight expanded row. but can't able to the clicked row

Comment: Please post your current code.

Comment: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-detail.component.ts  This it the demo source file. we need highlight the expanded row  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
findParentNode(parentName, childObj) {
let tempNodeObj = childObj.parentNode;
while(tempNodeObj.tagName != parentName) {
  tempNodeObj = tempNodeObj.parentNode;
}
return tempNodeObj;
}

this.findParentNode('DATATABLE-BODY-ROW',$event.target);
```

this will help to find you the data table row element

```
this.render.addClass(findParentNode,"row-expanded");
```